# How to change the value of hidden form data when a radio button is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp-classic

What I want to do is when a user selects one of the radio button options its value will be passed to the hidden input's value. I can then use this data to display a particular form. How would I do this using Jquery/Javascript?

```
"<form id=""categoryedit""action=""category.asp"" method=""post"">" &_
                   "<input type=""hidden"" name=""stage"" value ="""">"&_
                   "<label for=""addcategory"">Add Category</label>"&_
                   "<input id=""addcategory"" type=""radio"" name=""addcategory"" value=""2""><br>" &_
                   "<label for=""deletecategory"">Delete Category</label>"&_
                   "<input id=""deletecategory"" type=""radio"" name=""deletecategory"" value=""4""><br>" &_
                   "<label for=""editcategory"">Edit Category</label>"&_
                   "<input id=""editcategory"" type=""radio"" name=""editcategory"" value=""6""><br>" &_
                   "<input class=""button"" type=""submit"" value=""Select"">" &_
                   "</form>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, all your `radio` buttons should have the same name so that they are grouped. Then this code should work for you:

```
$('#categoryedit input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
   $('#categoryedit input[type="hidden"]').val($(this).val());
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/gFwB5/)

Note in the example I change the `hidden` field so that it's visible, so you can see the code working.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for tip re grouping too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#categoryedit input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    $(this.form).find('input[name="stage"]').val(this.value)
})
```